# CTAN has been asking to change our web navigator today 31 -- mar -- 2018. It is ok?

Tags: discussion

When today accessed CTAN To read news about changes on packages with Opera 51 and in a second access, FireFox 59.0.2, obtained in both cases a superimposed panel that asked that I should update my navigator, because CTAN due to the lack of funds, have recruited the assistance of a firm to create revenue placing ads. The link to the advertising partner goes to **nsa.gov**; my question is:

Is this legitimate or its a hack?

Comment: Or it's April fools' day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 1st of April is the day dedicated to jokes.

For more infos, see here: [How to draw a fish?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361547/how-to-draw-a-fish)

Comment: I fell to the joke. But in a globalized world, not in every place is the same date. Here today is 31 march. But its genial! I laughed a lot and feel relieved. Previously, I had cleaned the history and related files in case of doubt.

Comment: @djnavas I think CTAN is a US site, and it's already April 1st there (at least on the East Coast). Happy fools' day!

Comment: @djnavas Btw, once I fell in Halloween's joke, that's why they don't catch me anymore :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX: CTAN is either hosted in Germany or in UK, as far as I know and both are east of the US, concerning the time → actually 1st of April is coming earlier to Europe (and even earlier in Asia) than to America ... unless calculated in UTC

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oooh, I thought it was American!

Comment: @CarLaTeX: No, I remembered that the main CTAN server seems to be 'Comedy' which is run by DANTE

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oooh there's always something to learn!

Comment: @djnavas According to an esteemed community member, it would be much easier if everybody sticked to Greenwich time. ;-)

Comment: @egreg The same esteemed community member eats pineapple pizza, he can't be taken as an example :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX: he actually can, young padawan. After all, _abusus non tollit usum_. 

Comment: @PauloCereda Oh, I am padawan, I thought I was Milanese! (Only egreg can understand it).

Comment: Isn't that off-topic on meta? All the other april fool's and halloween questions are on the main page.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, probably off-topic but I don't think it is very useful on the main since April 2nd...